# KDE Plasma got error in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, kde

So I installed sddm pack in my Ubuntu then change the login screen to KDE and desktop session to Plasma. When I login to my account i get KDE boot screen and when it stops the ring, I got the cursor and I got a message box said:

> "All shell packages missing. Contact your distro"

Then I hit Enter, it closes the box and nothing happened. I got stuck in KDE boot screen with no dock, no menu bar, no icon, nothing, just KDE boot screen.

Specs:

- VAIO Z series (VGN-Z56GG-B)
- Intel Core 2 Duo P9700(2.8Ghz, i386)
- nVidia GeForce 9300 GS and Mobile 4 Intel Chipset
- OS: Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 dualboot

Please help!

Comment: Can you post the exact message? Maybe a photo of that?

Comment: i cant sorry because i got stuck at kde bootscreen so no screenshots

Comment: How did you install KDE?   You shouldn't get that with an install of `kubuntu-desktop` (ie. all packages), so did you miss packages?  Kubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-reaches-end-of-kubuntu-support/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support;. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with KDE is still on-topic here though.

Comment: I think I didn't mention that installing Kubuntu-desktop fails every time

Comment: c2d processors are *amd64* and not *i386*.  see https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42599/intel-core2-duo-processor-p9700-6m-cache-2-80-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb.html  (where *amd64* is called *intel(r)64*)  ... *I've performed a QA-test of jammy (what will be 22.04 on release) on a c2d-e6320 this arvo*   We can only provide assistance with what you've provided us; which is no messages; no logs & details that fit user mistake(s) better than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reinstall Kubuntu task package by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop^
```

In the end of above line note `^` - it means task package, so all KDE packages will be installed as in normal Kubuntu system.

Then reboot.

Comment: thanks but.... there's one more thing. im tired of installing sddm so... i reconfig it to lightdm and now the os is bricked. no other ways to fix than reset the volume with windows 8.1. i will be updating status and let you know if its fixed. again i'll be using 16.04 EOL version since both two of these os got the same plasma error